# Circles in matplotlib overlapping when they should not

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two circles in python using matplotlib. I chose their positions such that they should not overlap. However, in the plot it looks like they do. Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

[image: overlapping circles]

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 5000

    radius = 0.0025
    positions = np.array([[0.5, 0.05], [0.5 + 2*radius + 0.001, 0.05]])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.cla() 
    ax.set_xlim((0, 1.0))
    ax.set_ylim((0, 0.1))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    for n in range(len(positions)):
        circle = plt.Circle((positions[n, 0], positions[n, 1]), radius=radius,                              color='r')
        ax.add_patch(circle)
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig("circles.png")
```

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the Circle patch is drawn as a face and an edge - the edge has a thickness, which is what is overlapping.

We can resolve this by setting the `facecolor` to red, and the `edgecolor` to `None`, so it doesn't get plotted.

For example:

```
circle = plt.Circle((positions[n, 0], positions[n, 1]), radius=radius,
                    facecolor='r', edgecolor='None')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed!